# Why do isosteric molecules have similar shapes?

Tags: molecular-structure

**Isosteres** (*Definition*): `Isosteres are atoms, molecules, or ions of similar size containing the same number of atoms and valence electrons.`<sup>[1]</sup>

***Questions:***

A. Why should they have same molecular structure (or geometry)?<sup>[2]</sup><sup>[3]</sup>

B. Are there exceptions where isosteres don't have same structure? If yes, please give one.

<sup>1. [Chemcool Dictionary, Definition of Isosteres](https://www.chemicool.com/definition/isosteres.html#:~:text=Isosteres%20are%20atoms%2C%20molecules%2C%20or%20ions%20of%20similar%20size%20containing%20the%20same%20number%20of%20atoms%20and%20valence%20electrons.) 
 2. [Wikipedia: Isostere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isostere#:~:text=or%20ions%20with-,similar%20shape,-and%20often%20electronic) 
 3. [Chemcool Dictionary, Definition of Isosteres](https://www.chemicool.com/definition/isosteres.html#:~:text=In%20general%2C%20isosteric%20molecules%20have%20the%20same%20shape.)</sup>

Comment: Isosteric molecules have similar shapes because that's what the word "isosteric" really means.

Comment: @IvanNeretin My teacher just gave the definition as "isosteres are those molecules which are isoelectronic (have the same number of total electrons) and have the same number of atoms", for example CO₂ and N₂O. Interestingly, in Wikipedia, I found the definition as "Classical Isosteres are molecules or ions with similar shape and often electronic properties." Are these two definitions equivalent? Does the fact that they have same number of electrons and atoms imply the fact that they will have same structural arrangement? And are there exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let's get this straight. "**Iso**" means "***same***" and "**stereos**" means "***shape***", so "**isosteric**" means "***having the same shape***". That's what it means because that's what it says, as clearly as the day. There is nothing more to it.

This is the correct definition, and the other one is wrong. See, butane and isobutane contain the same number of atoms (even atoms *of the same elements*) and of valence electrons, so what? Do they have the same shape? Definitely no.

So it goes.